# NHinernate - Serializing Criteria to json and back. for a web interface usage

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I have a web interface with a lot of data grids that allow the user passing a search criteria to the server.
I don't want to actually build an explicit method that will handle each grid individually, so I thought to allow passing JSON criteria from the client to the server.

This code

```
string res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Restrictions.Eq("id", "1"));
```

will return will return `{"PropertyName":"id","Value":"1"}` which is exactly what I wanted to pass from the client - perfect.

but this code with `or` statement:

```
string res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.Eq("id", "1"),Restrictions.Eq("id", "2")))
```

will return `{}`

What is the way to convert **JSON into a Criteria** and **back** in nHibernate.
To be more accurate, I have something like this in the client, and I want my server to support it. I can serialize the client ui to json.

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The empty json serialization happens because newtonsoft can only serialize public fields.
The code below will serialize all fields of a class regardless of its visibility.

```
public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                        .Select(p => base.CreateProperty(p, memberSerialization))
                    .Union(type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                               .Select(f => base.CreateProperty(f, memberSerialization)))
                    .ToList();
        props.ForEach(p => { p.Writable = true; p.Readable = true; });
        return props;
    }
}
...
var myOrs = Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.Eq("id", "1"), Restrictions.Eq("id", "2"));

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new MyContractResolver()
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myOrs, settings);
```

Now to deserialize this json we have a problem, the NHibernate classes are either `abstract` or don't have a public empty constructor.

You will need to create a custom class to deserialize.

```
public class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented yet");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        if (obj.Value<string>("Op") == "or")
        {
            var leftJObject = obj["LeftHandSide"];
            var rightJObject = obj["RightHandSide"];
            var left = new SimpleExpression(leftJObject.Value<string>("PropertyName"), GetJTokenValue(leftJObject["Value"]), leftJObject.Value<string>("Op"));
            var right = new SimpleExpression(rightJObject.Value<string>("PropertyName"), GetJTokenValue(rightJObject["Value"]), rightJObject.Value<string>("Op"));
            return Restrictions.Or(left, right);
        }
        //TODO: The rest of the restrictions
        return null;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private object GetJTokenValue(JToken token)
    {
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            return token.Value<string>();
        }
        else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Integer)
        {
            return token.Value<Int32>();
        }
        //TODO: The rest of the types

        return null;
    }
}
...
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AbstractCriterion>(json, new MyConverter());
```